# Android google Map is showing old location

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

There is an issue with our app regarding map location.

When the map screen is loaded, map shows last GPS location on screen, which may be inaccurate. Sometimes it takes quite a while to get an updated location info from GPS, and sometimes it fails outright.

In either of these conditions user is presented with inaccurate location information from last known location. We should avoid this...

We need to be able to show a progress bar or spinner to user while the GPS information updated and only then show the new updated location on map.

How can we achieve this any helps is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Override OnLocationChanged method Whereever you are implementing LocationListener..

Like this:--

```
 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

  public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) {
   GeoPoint myGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(
    (int)(argLocation.getLatitude()*1000000),
    (int)(argLocation.getLongitude()*1000000));

  GeoPoint newGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(myGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), myGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6());
  Toast.makeText(GetApplicationContext(),"Lat:"+newGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1000000,"Lang:"+newGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1000000)
  }
```

Hope it will help you..